# Getting InnerText from HTMLElement of WebBrowser using Python and Pywin

Tags: python, vba, win32com, sap-gui, pywin

I'm trying to get `InnerText` property of `HTMLElement` of already opened WebBrowser (from SAP GUI Scripting `GuiHTMLViewer` object > `BrowserHandle` > `Document`) using pywin (win32com) lib on Python.

I got a WebBrowser, which have Document property (object HTMLDocument), which have methods, for example:

```
getElementsByTagName(string TagName)
```

https://cdn3.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/3/25/04b5bce44c15b2f06369d010b71d9a70-full.png

When I try to use this method on Python

```py
document = browser_handle.document
elements = document.getElementsByTagName("td")
```

it says

> TypeError: getElementsByTagName() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

but when I try to use this method on VBA, it's success:

```vb
Set BrowserHandle = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsSO33_TAB1/tabpTAB1/ssubSUB1:SAPLSO33:1100/cntlCONTROL/shellcont/shell").BrowserHandle
Set Document = BrowserHandle.Document
Set Elements = Document.getElementsByTagName("td")
MsgBox Elements.Item(0).InnerText
```

Comment: Sorry, it's just one typo.
Actually there is 
`elements = document.getElementsByTagName("td")`

Comment: Why SAP tag? it is a python/vba question

Comment: It's GuiHTMLViewer object. I'm trying to read SOST messages for backend testing.

GuiHTMLViewer->BrowserHandle->Document